# Sqlite python - how to sort by date(newest first)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite DB that has a column called `date` which is a `DATETIME`. I have used this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY date(date) DESC")
```

However, it gives me the oldest first, and I want it the other way around. I a newbie to SQL, so could someone help me out?

EDIT: Just to be clear for anyone wondering, this is the correct answer:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY Date DESC")
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Use "ASC" instead of "DESC". Full syntax here: http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#ordering-term

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest you to try the inverse:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY date ASC")
```

and see if it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you sure the column is defined as date?

Comment: I used `cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Posts(Id INTEGER, Title TEXT, Content TEXT, date DATETIME)")`. So to my knowledge, yes.

Comment: What' exactly is `date(date)`? Shouldn't it be like "SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY date ASC;"

Comment: I'm not actually sure(as I said, I am very new to SQL) I got it from googeling it. I changed it to `SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY date ASC` and it still sorts oldest first. EDIT: It seems I just forgot to save. This works

Comment: I'm glad, I'll modify the answer to remove the `date(date)` part.

Answer (score 0):

try not to use "date" word as a column name when creating a database table, because this name is reserved for the systems, try to change the name from date to another name, and try again.